# Super slow performance of querying a DataTable with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code similar to this structure:
my table has 108000 rows.
This datatable is really just I read a tab delimited text file to process so I put it in a datatable.

```
private void Foo(DataTable myDataTable)
{

        List<string> alreadyProcessed = new List<string>();
        foreach(DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            string current = row["Emp"].ToString().Trim();
            if (alreadyProcessed.Contains(current))
                continue;
            alreadyProcessed.Add(current);
            var empRows = from p in myDataTable.AsEnumerable
                where p["Emp"].ToString().Trim() == current
                select new EmpClass
                {
                    LastName = (string) p["lName"],
                    // some more stuff similr
                };

        // do some stuff with that EmpClass but they shouldn't take too long
        }
    }
```

Running such a thing is taking more than 15 minutes. How can I improve this?

Comment: try switching `alreadyProcessed` to be `HashSet<string>`

Comment: Besides that you might want to group by Emp column, so that at least you don't have to filter the rows continuously in the second block

Comment: The DataTable dt seems to be defined outside the scope of this method, you may wish to enumerate myDataTable in the same place, so that you're not having to enumerate the entire table on each iteration of the foreach loop (where you've not already seen the `Emp` in question), and you're accessing a sole in-memory version.

Comment: @Brizio can you please give an example of "group by" in this case

Comment: What is `dt`, is it supposed to be `myDataTable`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  yes copy paste error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather naive rewrite of your code.

Instead of tracking which employees you have already processed, let's just group all rows by their employees and process them each separately.

```
var rowsPerEmployee =
    (from DataRow row in dt.Rows
     let emp = row["Emp"].ToString().Trim()
     group row by emp into g
     select g)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.ToArray());

foreach (var current in rowsPerEmployee.Keys)
{
    var empRows = rowsPerEmployee[current];
    ... rest of your code here, note that empRows is not all the rows for a single employee
    ... and not just the lastname or similar
}
```

This will first group the entire datatable by the employee and create a dictionary from employee to rows for that employee, and then loop on the employees and get the rows.

Comment: Thank you very much for thinking through this, I will try it.

Comment: "row["Emp"].ToString().Trim()"  doesn't exist :( From the time I start typing ToString() it doesn't understand it anymore.

Comment: **Every** .NET object has a `.ToString()` method.

Comment: Ok figured out what is wrong with the syntax that doesn't compile. You had used dt.Rows but .Rows is not "typed" so it can't infer the type for the query so I replaced it with dt.Select() which is typed so it compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You should do Group By `"EMP"`, otherwise you're going through each row and for some rows you're querying the whole table. Something like this

```
from p in myDataTable.AsEnumerable
group p by p.Field<string>("Emp") into g
select new { Emp = g.Key, 
             Data = g.Select(gg=>new EmpClass 
                                  { 
                                     LastName = gg.Field<string>("lName")
                                  }
                             )
           }
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of "group by" in my case with that code in context. Thanks

Comment: Thanks but where did the "where" clause go?

Comment: This is to replace the whole `foreach` loop. The `where` is done by the grouping of data by the emp column

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might slow things down for you in the linq statement is, how much data you're selecting! you write 'select new EmpClass', and depending on how many columns (and rows/information for that matter) your selecting to become your output may slow things drastically down for you. Other tips and tricks to work on that problem may be found in: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/06/24/five-tips-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: it is just 10 rows in the select new I am selecting